# how to add border radius on plotbackground area in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I browsed Highcharts api reference doc, there is an option to set plotBackgroundColor, but how to set border radius on plot area?

Is there some hack to add border radius on plot area?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, there is only `plotBackgroundColor`, not radius in the options. However, you can add that radius, using `Element.attr()`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/wmr9w5L3/

```
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
            ]
        },
        events: {
            load: function () {
                this.plotBackground.attr({
                    rx: 100,
                    ry: 100
                })
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: It's still valid, demo works without errors. Make sure you tried with `plotBackgroundColor` set in the options.